# Oil :water partition coefficients

Tags: solutions, reference-request

Is there a database or a website with a list of oil : water partition coefficients of substances ?

I actually want the oil:water partition coefficients of :

cholesterol, starch , methyl citrate , citric acid , iso- citrate , methyl urea , carotene

Comment: There are a wide range of partition coefficient predictors that can estimate logP on the basis of varying structural heuristics - are you potentially interested in these?

Comment: @RichardTerrett I really don't know what all this means. I am a biology student and would like to know these values so that I can predict which materials would pass through the plasma membrane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two places where you can find predicted values of LogP (the oil:water partitioning coefficient) are chemicalize.org and Wolfram Alpha.  Both provide a predicted value for most of the compounds you are interested in (chemicalize provides a complete set, assuming you mean betacarotene).

### Examples

[This link](http://www.chemicalize.org/structure/#!mol=cholesterol&source=calculate) provides a direct link to the output of the cholesterol page from Chemicalize.org and shows the logP value on the left hand side (7.11)

To get the logp from Wolfram alpha you must search for logp  and then chose the predicted link that appears when no results are returned.  [This link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=logp+cholesterol&a=*DPClash.ChemicalE.cholesterol-_*Cholesterol.dflt-&a=*DPClash.ChemicalP.logp-_*PredictedLogPHydrophobicity-) should get you to the value obtained from Wolfram Alpha (7.02).